# java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable (cannot infer type-variable(s) R

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream, reduce, collect

I try to write some stream code that reduces `report` objects into one `report` object.

I have this java code that 
take strings (requests) get http response --> pass it to some comparison with old response saved in memory.

I want to collect n `compare results` into on `Result` object

and eventually I want to aggregate m `report` objects into one object.

I have this code

request is of type `string`

sumReport of type `report`

compare2 of type `compare result`

and:

```
        Report report = requestsList
                .parallelStream()
                .map(request ->
                                getResponse(request, e2EResultLongBL, e2EResultLongFresh)
                )
                .map(response -> compareToBl(response, e2EResultLongBL))
                .collect(null,
                        (sumReport, compare2) ->
                        {
                            if (sumReport == null)
                            {
                                sumReport = new Report();
                            }
                            sumReport.add(compare2);
                            return  sumReport;
                        },
                        (report1, report2) ->
                        {
                            Report report3 = new Report();
                            report3.add(report2);
                            return report3;
                        });
```

why do I got this error?

```
Error:(174, 21) java: no suitable method found for collect(<nulltype>,(sumReport[...]rt; },(report1,r[...]t3; })
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super com.waze.routing.automation.dataModel.ComparisonResult>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R
        (argument mismatch; unexpected return value))
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super com.waze.routing.automation.dataModel.ComparisonResult,A,R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Comment: *How does the mechanism work*: this is described by the javadoc, in great length. Have you read it? Do you think null is a valid value for its first argument? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-. The 2 other arguments are BiConsumers. Does a BiConsumer(s accept method return something?

Comment: `collect` is a *mutable* reduction. You are not supposed to `return` anything in the accumulator or the combiner.

Comment: @PaulBoddington thanks. I'm confused. How should I re-write the code if I don't want a list of `report` but one aggregated report eventually?

Comment: @user1065869 I'm not sure. You need to show us the types of everything.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so what do I need to use in order to get eventually one report?

Comment: `.collect(Report::new, Report::add, Report::add)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, if you call `reduce()` instead, it'll compile.

Usually, the first argument can provide some constraints for type inference; unfortunately, you are using `null` here. By looking at the method invocation alone, there is no way telling what `R` can be. Fortunately, the method invocation is in an assignment context, so `R` could be inferred as `Report`.

The only problem is the value-return statement inside the lambda body, while the functional type is supposed to be void-return. It works with `reduce()` because of different return types.

The compiler uses return statements in lambda body to constraint the type of the lambda, which is useful for example in overload resolution

```
    ExecutorService es= ...;
    es.submit( ()->{ return new Object(); } );      // submit(Callable)
    es.submit( ()->{        new Object(); } );      // submit(Runnable)
```

Handling `void` is a tricky business, e.g. this code does not compile, which is reasonable

```
    Executor ex = null;
    ex.execute( ()->{ return new Object(); } ); // error, ()->void is expected
```

However, these two forms do compile, which is also reasonable and useful

```
    ex.execute(()->new Object());
    ex.execute(Object::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

At a best guess -- you haven't provided much detail -- I'd expect what you need is just `collect(Report::new, Report::add, Report::add)`, which says more or less: create new Reports for accumulators, call `Report.add` to add an element to a `Report`, and also call `Report.add` (maybe a different overload) to combine a second `Report` into the first `Report`).

Comment: I'll add types. sorry. can you modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: do calling same method twice make sense? `Report::add, Report::add`

Comment: It looks like it's different overloads, but yes, it makes sense.  And it's not types I need, exactly, it's pretty much API details on all the classes you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to a JDK bug: in some cases the JDK 1.8.0_25 does not reconizes lambda properly.

A similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368060/why-this-code-compiles-with-jdk8u45-and-above-but-not-with-jdk8u25) comes to the same conclusion.

I suggest you update your sdk version (*java -version*) to at least 1.8.0_45